# How does the payment gateway works in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, custom, payment-gateway

I want to integrate my own payment gateway in Magento 2. I've read many topics, studied the sample code from the [Magento 2 repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) and the braintree module.

However I've not found great posts about the used patterns and how they works. I would like to understand what's the process and the functional flow behind this.
Actually I can implement the payment gateway but it's completely useless if I can't understand how it works.. So what I need is some technical logic explanation and what are the different process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, now Magento has any docs about payment integrations based on Payment Gateway, but docs in progress and should be published in the nearest future.

One exception is - [How to add a payment method to checkout page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html).

But, you can read some start topics:

- [Payment Gateway API](https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-gateway-api)
- [Payment Adapter configuration](https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-adapter-configuration)

Also, I've created few sequence diagrams, they describe base flow:
[image: Payment Gateway flow]
And example flow for an authorize payment action
[image: Authorization flow]

**UPD**: Magento team has published documentation about [payment integrations](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check out it and give my feedback, if I've still some questions :) With your sequence diagrams it's a way clearer!!